# Angular 2 Get keys from localStorage and display in a list

Tags: html, angular, list, local-storage

I'm trying to display localStorage data into a list. I've tried to bind it with *ngFor But I dont seem to be getting it right.

Comment: There is no link between your `for` and the `*ngFor` displayed. More information is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variable of type array

```
users: any = [];
```

and then

```
this.users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));
```

Comment: I've tried this but it complains that it must be of the type array or likewise, JSON isnt accaptable for the *ngFor function

Comment: How does your local storage look like

Comment: Key: User Value: {"name":"Kevin","country":"Canada","about":"Test","image":""}

Answer (score 0):

ngFor only work on array not in objects. Push your localstorage data into an array. Then use ngFor.

**Updated**

It is better not to use `ngFor` because you don't have repeated interface. I suggest you to go like this

```
localData = { Key: User, Value: {"name":"Kevin","country":"Canada","about":"Test","image":""‌​}}
```

In you HTML

```
<ul>
   <li>{{localData.key}}</li>
   <li>{{localData.value.name}}</li>
   <li>{{localData.value.country}}</li>
   <li>{{localData.value.about}}</li>
   <li>{{localData.value.image}}</li>
</ul>
```

I hope this may help you. If you still need *ngFor usage comment below. I will help

Comment: Could you elaborate how this could be done with a code example? This is my localStorage JSON 
`Key: User Value {"name":"Kevin","country":"Canada","about":"Test","image":""}`